# Supermicro X9DAi shuts down for a long time

Tags: boot, bios, shutdown, supermicro

After updating BIOS (ver.3.3 now), the computer (Supermicro X9DAi on 7037A-i chassis, 2x Xeon E5-2680 v1, 128 GB RDIMM) shuts down for a long time (the power button does not light, but the fans and drives are noisy) it lasts about a minute and then computer shuts down completely.
I can’t understand why this is happening, so I have two questions:

- Does anyone have a previous version of BIOS (2014 year version)?
- Does anyone know what this behavior is related to (can this be fixed by BIOS settings)?

I updated the BIOS, because my system sometimes could not load the BIOS (POST codes did not pass, only dark screen) and stood for a long time, rotating the fans, but not loading - I also do not understand why this happens.